# rotating edge loops individually on their own axis

Tags: modeling

I would like to know how to rotate edge loops individually on their own axis. I tried doing this with pivot point as individual origins and rotating along normals X with normal as the transformation axis. Actually, I tried all combinations with all the axis, but none worked.

I need the selected edges rotated individually 45 degrees forward. [image]

Comment: I have found a way by applying rotation opperator with 45 degrees separately but is there a way with rotation tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the setup.

1. model your flower and delete all the rest of the petals leaving one.
2. since there is 5 sides each petals need to rotate 72 degree.
3. Using array modifier with a rotated empty I reconstructed the flower.
4. Now I can modify one petal to make sure all the rest of the petals follow.

Here is the blend file I created ...

1. Select edit mode.
2. Select edge mode.
3. Make sure to select the edge you want to rotate from last (The Active Element)
4. Set pivot point to "Active Element"
5. Hit <kbd>N</kbd> to open navigation panel in 3d view.
6. Look for Transform Orientation tab.
7. Hit the "+" button to setup Transform Orientation to the face you want to rotate.
8. Remember to choose from the list of newly created Transform Orientation called "face" if there are more than one it should look like "face.001 or face.002"
9. Activate rotation and hit <kbd>Y</kbd> to rotate in the Y axis.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is so deep and technical therefore not very artist-friendly. Sadly the rotation tool cannot do that.  I have used different method. I selected my edge loop, did the rotation operation then applied that operation (shift + r) to the edge loops I needed.

Comment: To understand your requirement for this behavior. Do you need it for modeling or animation? If it's for animation the above method works. If it's modeling then I would suggest for this scenario you should apply move instead of rotation. I don't know if it's possible, but from my arsenal of methods ... this is the way I do it if it's a multi-angled object like a flower.

Comment: It is for learning purposes. Just free modeling and learning blender. Just thought it was possible to free form model(rotate) the tool and the edges would act the same. Thanks again. Your explanation gave me more understanding!