# Rotation of face loop

Tags: modeling

Here is a selected face loop. I want to rotate all of the faces to be more flat or less flat; along something like a *Y-Normal*.

*Edge Loop in normal position:*

[image: Loop]

*What a more flat rotation might look like (achieved with Z-Scaling):*

[image: l2]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide reference images of what you want to achieve, it's not clear what you are trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know how to describe "rotation toward/along the z axis" in words.

Comment: Could this be it? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70153/rotating-edge-loops-individually-on-their-own-axis?rq=1

Comment: What if you scale Z instead of rotating?

Comment: try selecting rotating the faces along their local axis while transforming in "individual elements" mode.

Comment: Thank you all. Scaling with z does the thing but does not keep the height of faces.

Comment: @Yvain I did try this but it's the same as global mode.

Comment: I mean the **pivot point** http://pasteboard.co/yL5k5XlOa.png
precisely called "individual origins"